# Verification Bot not adding roles

Tags: discord.js

I keep getting thrown "client.guilds.get(...).member(...).roles.add is not a function" and I've tried numerous threads on changing lines, but none really solved the issue that I had.

I've tried to change message.author to message.member, but it didn't seem to work and gave me plentyful more errors.

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.author.token || message.channel.type !== `dm`) return
    if (message.content !== (verifymsg.replace('{token}', message.author.token))) return
    message.channel.send({
        embed: {
            color: Math.floor(Math.random() * (0xFFFFFF + 1)),
            description: completemsg,
            timestamp: new Date(),
            footer: {
                text: `Verification Success`
            }
        }
    })
    client.guilds.get(config.guild).member(message.author).roles.add(config.role) // ensure this is a string in the config ("")
        .then(console.log(`TOKEN: ${message.author.token} :: Role ${config.role} added to member ${message.author.id}`))
        .catch(console.error)
})
```

The user is supposed to get a role "Member" after verifying with the line given to them to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error says, `GuildMember.roles.add()` is not a function. [`GuildMember.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) returns a Collection, and `add()` is not a method of a Collection or a Map (Collection extends Map).

You should use [`GuildMember.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole).

```js
client.guilds.get(config.guild).member(message.author).addRole(config.role)
```

Comment: Happy to help! If your problem is solved, you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.